# Writing entries of sum of matrix row outer products in matrix notation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the matrix $T \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and another matrix $S \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ defined by

$$ S_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{l=1}^n T_{ik} T_{jl} $$

How can I write matrix $S$ in terms of $T$ using standard linear algebra expressions.

I see that I can write the entries of $S$ in terms of outer products of rows of $T$ i.e.

$$ S_{ij} = \boldsymbol{1}^T T_{i} T_{j}^T \boldsymbol{1} $$

where $\boldsymbol{1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector of ones and $T_i$ is the $i$th row of T. I don't see how to progress from here however. I'm guessing the expression may involve a Kronecker product as this contains all the terms used if we aggregate the values of $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $S=T \, E \, T^t,$ where $E$ is an $n\times n$-matrix consisting of 1s only.

You see that this works when you write it out as
$$
S_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{l=1}^n T_{ik}\, 1 \, T_{jl} = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{l=1}^n T_{ik} \, E_{kl} \, (T^t)_{lj}.
$$

Comment: Also note that this means your matrix $S$ has really low rank --- no more than rank $E$, which is $1$.

Comment: An alternative, closer in spirit to OPs original approach, is to write $$S = S = T \boldsymbol{1}  \boldsymbol{1}^tT^t.$$ Of course, this works because $\boldsymbol{1}  \boldsymbol{1}^t$ is exactly your matrix $E$.